# SQL - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I exported my database, because I changing server.
Now I want to import my SQL Dump, but I getting error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"' at line 1
```

Here is begin of my dump:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.5 
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Czas wygenerowania: 28 Cze 2016, 12:42
-- Wersja serwera: 5.5.32-cll
-- Wersja PHP: 5.3.17

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a dump command. Please use the *proper* tags.

Comment: The error message implies that `-- ` does not denote a comment which is weird because https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/comment-syntax/ says it is and the export is the one that put it there...

Comment: `show variables where variable_name like '%version%';` and see what is allowed for each

Comment: What is the command that used that dump file and got that error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing server *types?* (Microsoft SQL, MySQL, Postgres...)
If so, that will affect how the SQL works. You will need to use the appropriate syntax for the SQL version you are using.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
```

On a side note, your error makes it appear like the "--" is what is throwing off the import.